# Ubuntu 14.04 with Emulex fibre channel. Finds target, but doesn't create device

Tags: ubuntu, fibre-channel, emulex

I have a Cisco branded Emulex LightPulse LPE12002 in a Cisco UCS server running Ubuntu 14.04, and I am trying to connect to about 15TB of remote storage configured for it. I don't know where to start, but here's what I have done.

First, when I issue `systool -c fc_remote_ports -v -d`, I get a result like the following.

```
  Class Device = "0-2"
  Class Device path = "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.1/host2/rport-2:0-2/fc_remote_ports/rport-2:0-2"
    dev_loss_tmo        = "30"
    fast_io_fail_tmo    = "off"
    maxframe_size       = "2048 bytes"
    node_name           = "0x50060e8005be9526"
    port_id             = "0x010200"
    port_name           = "0x50060e8005be9526"
    port_state          = "Online"
    roles               = "FCP Target"
    scsi_target_id      = "0"
    supported_classes   = "Class 3"
    uevent              = 

    Device = "rport-2:0-2"
    Device path = "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.1/host2/rport-2:0-2"
      uevent              =
```

This looks like it is the right target, since it's an "FCP Target" and I have confirmed that the port_name is indeed the WWN of the 15TB storage target I am trying to connect to.

The issue is that Linux doesn't create a device in /dev that I can use.  I have a sg0 device, but that's mapped to sda, which is from the raid controller for local disks.

I have done the following to try and make linux recognize the storage.
`rescan-scsi-bus`
`echo "1" > /sys/class/fc_host/host{1,2}/issue_lip`
`echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host{1,2}/scan`
multiple reboots
verified the lpfc driver is loaded

None of these seem to work for creating a usable device.  I am not using multipath currently, even though it is a 2 port FC card, I am just testing with one port connected and with exposed storage.

Any ideas?

Comment: This systool output only means your device is visible. It didn't do anything with your device until now, only your scsi adapter queried (and found) its existence. Probably your driver wasn't loaded automatically, and probably because it doesn't exist. But there is a linux driver existing, with google I found here: http://www.emulex.com/downloads/emulex/drivers/linux/  .

Comment: a port_id of 0x010200 isn't a valid pWWN format

Comment: sorry, port_name, I'll edit that. Also, the lpfc is the open source emulex FC driver that's been in the kernel for a while now, and it's confirmed loaded.